# What does it mean to be integral over something

Tags: number-theory

I don't understand what it means to say $\mathbb Q[\sqrt d]$ to be integral over $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Did you mean $\,\Bbb Z[\sqrt{d}]?\ \ $

Comment: Q[√d] integral over Z

Comment: Then it is false, since proper fractions such as $\,1/2\,$ are not integral over $\,\Bbb Z,\,$ i.e. not the root of a monic polynomial $\in\Bbb Z[x],\,$ by the Rational Root Test.

Answer (score 2):

This terminology comes from commutative algebra. (Really it originates in number theory, but that's beside the point.)

> **Definition:** Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $S \subseteq R$ a subring of $R$. (Here "subring" means $S$ is a commutative ring with the same unity element as $R$.) An element $r$ of $R$ is said to be **integral** over $S$ if $r$ is a root of a monic polynomial in $S[x]$, *i.e.*, if there exist $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $s_0,\ldots,s_{n-1} \in S$ such that
>   $$
>     s_0 + s_1 r + \ldots + s_{n-1}r^{n-1} + r^n = 0.
> $$
>   The ring $R$ is called **integral** over $S$ if every element of $R$ is integral over $S$.

In algebraic number theory, one often studies finite extensions $K$ of the rational numbers, such as $K = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$. By convention, one says that an element $a \in K$ is **integral** (without reference to a base ring) if $a$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$. In other words, we say that $a \in K$ is integral if $p(a) = 0$ for some monic $p(x) \in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. As it turns out, the set $\mathfrak{O}_K$ of integral elements of $K$ is a ring (called the "ring of integers of $K$"), and the relationship between $\mathfrak{O}_K$ and $K$ is very much analogous to the relationship between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. This motivates the calling the elements of $\mathfrak{O}_K$ the integers of $K$ (or at least thinking about them this way).

Regarding your particular example, the ring $K = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt d]$ for $d \in\mathbb{Z}$ is *not* integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, but its subring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt d]$ is. This can actually be seen because even $\mathbb{Q}$ is *not* integral over $\mathbb{Z}$; if $q \in\mathbb{Q}$ is not an integer, then neither is $p(q)$ for any monic polynomial $p(x)$ with integer coefficients, and hence $p(q) \neq 0$ for any such $p(x)$.
On the other hand, every element $r \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt d]$ is of the for $r = a+b\sqrt{d}$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, and hence satisfies

$$
    (r-a)^2 - b^2d = 0.
$$

Therefore $r$ is a root of the following monic polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$:

$$
    p(x) = (x-a)^2 - b^2d = x^2 - 2ax + (a^2 - b^2d).
$$

It's also worth noting that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt d]$ is *not* always equal to $\mathfrak{O}_K$, instead being a proper subring of $\mathfrak{O}_K$ for certain values of $d$. Specifically, for any squarefree $d \neq 0$ and $K = \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$, we have that
$$
    \mathfrak{O}_K = \begin{cases}\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] &\text{if }d\equiv 1 \pmod{4}\\
                                  \mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}\right] &\text{if }d\equiv 2,3 \pmod{4}.
                     \end{cases}
$$
This accounts for all such $d$, since $d$ is assumed to be squarefree (and hence not divisible by $4$).

Answer (score 1):

A ring $S$ is an integral overring of ring $R$ iff each element of $S \supset R$ satisfies a monic polynomial with coefficients in $R$.

Now $\mathbb{Q}$ is not an *integral* overring of $\mathbb{Z}$, nor is the bigger overring $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ an integral overring of the integers.  For example, $\frac{1}{2}$ does not satisfy a monic polynomial with integer coefficients.

As Bill Dubuque points out (see Comment above), this is a consequence of the [Rational Root Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem),  which indeed implies that if a rational number $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, then $r \in \mathbb{Z}$.  There are no elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ that are not already in $\mathbb{Z}$.

When this happens for the inclusion of a domain $R$ in its quotient field $F$, we say the domain is *integrally closed*, meaning that the formation of the quotient field doesn't produce any new integral elements (over the base domain).

However $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ for $d \in \mathbb{Z}$ that is *not* a perfect square *does* create new integral elements (over $\mathbb{Z}$).  In particular, $\sqrt{d}$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ because it satisfies $x^2 - d = 0$, but $\sqrt{d}$ does not belong to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Happily all the elements of overring $S$ that are integral over $R$ will form an overring $\overline{R}$ that we call the *integral closure* of $R$ in $S$.  So perhaps the Question was prompted by a discussion (elsewhere) about the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$, which would be a classic problem of *algebraic integers*.

Comment: why not?  what does it mean to satisfy a monic polynomial

Comment: A monic polynomial has leading coefficient one (the identity in the base ring $R$ generally, or in your specific case, integer $1$).  A ring element satisfies a polynomial ("is a root of the polynomial") if and only if substituting that ring element for the unknown ("indeterminate") of the polynomial evaluates to zero (in the overring $S$).